# How can i check if a string has all characters of a substring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, substring

I need to find if a string has all characters of a substring. So for a 7 char string i want to know if the chars of a 5 char substings are in the string, without repeating letters (if substring has 2 letters a, then the string needs at max 2 letters a).

For exemple :

```
Substring = 'aabfy'
String1 = 'aabcfgy'
String2 = 'abcfgmy' 
String3 = 'aaabcfy'
```

Then String1 and String3 are True, but String2 is False. Because sub string is in 1 and 3 but not in 2 (double a, but it can also be any other letter).

I hope i explained myself, any questions i can and will answer.

Comment: Does the order matter, does it have to be a subsequence? In other words, would `'ybafaxyz'` be a valid containing string?

Comment: yes that will also be a valid string

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It's not a duplicate, the number of each character matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in the following way:

```
from collections import Counter

def contains_all(string, substring):
    c1, c2 = Counter(string), Counter(substring)
    return all(c1[x] >= c2[x] for x in c2)
```

This will ensure every character in the substring is at least as many times in the containing string.

```
>>> contains_all('aaabcfy', 'aabfy')
True
>>> contains_all('abcfgmy', 'aabfy')
False
>>> contains_all('aabcfgy', 'aabfy')
True
```

**Update:** A better version (thx to @HenadziRabkin for the hint), using `Counter` difference:

```
def contains_all(string, substring):
    return not (Counter(substring) - Counter(string))

self.cs = Counter(source)
# more efficient version
def countains_all(target):
    ct = Counter(target)
    for k,v in ct.items(): # Compare only target symbols
       if k not in self.cs or self.cs[k]- v < 0: # Break comparison if a source has number of expected symbol types less than a target 
         return False
    return True
```

Comment: It works! Thanks

Comment: you can substract Counters and check length difference of a result as an option

Comment: @HenadziRabkin Difference is a good approach, too.  However, length is not required, you can simply check for any remainder when subtracting the string from the substring. I added that version.

Comment: @user2390182 that's true, but be aware that this method is not optimal, it takes O(n) and checking every symbol for value difference equality to zero and abrupt circle if not is much more efficient. You have to check only symbols which has target substring you look for instead of ALL symbols which might have source string

Comment: @user2390182 in the efficient version you will have O(m) instead of O(n) where M - is a target length and n is a source length

Comment: @HenadziRabkin nah it is  O(m+n) in both cases. The `Counter(source), Counter(target)` calls already make that obvious.

Comment: @HenadziRabkin Actually, your "more efficient" version is quite equivalent to my original, just way more verbose and convoluted.

Comment: @user2390182 true, the only difference is that your first version doesn't stop comparisons at non-match. In the worst case they are the same. I tried all three versions in leetcode and "more efficient" one wins with pre-created source Counter outside the function

Comment: @user2390182 I have added an update and moved Counter(source) out of the function

Comment: @HenadziRabkin My first DOES stop at a non-match. `all` is short-circuiting. Creating the source counter once make sense if you test it against multiple targets. And you if part is still way to wordy as `if k not in self.cs or self.cs[k]- v < 0:` is the same as just `if self.cs[k] < v`

Comment: @user2390182 nice, I now know that 'all' is short-circuiting. But you anyway has to move creation of source-str-Counter out of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `str.count` in list comprehension, with `all`:

```
def f(s):
    return all(s.count(i)>=Substring.count(i) for i in Substring)
print(f(String1))
print(f(String2))
print(f(String3))
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
```

Comment: No need to build the spurious list which will render the early breaking of `all` pointless. Better pass it a generator. Also, repeated calls to `str.count` are bad in terms of performance as the entire string needs to be iterated for every char.

Comment: @schwobaseggl okay now?

Comment: Yes :) the second part still holds though.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Second part?

Comment: The repeated calls to count which make an easy linear function quadratic.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Lol, what can i do :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186615/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-u9-forward).

Comment: @U9-Forward i get an error : "expected a string or other character buffer object"

Comment: @Gundro Strange, may you copy and run again?

Comment: @schwobaseggl If my timings are correct, this solution is 10x faster than your solution using `Counter`.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Wow, that's sounds good for me :-)

Comment: @Tomothy32 If you use the given data, but certainly not for longer strings.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Well, given data is OP's data...

Comment: @schwobaseggl certainly has a point, trying it with longer strings (in the 5-digits) that return `True` makes the `Counter` solution 400x faster. (Of course, I'm testing the worst case scenario for this solution, as the `all` will never short-circuit.)